# Laptop external monitor

Tags: display, suspend, hdmi

Hoping somebody can help

I have a dell G5 5587 laptop running Hera, I have connected to external monitor via HDMI cable.

when the laptops lid is closed I can work on the external.
when the laptop gets suspended I can wake it up with USB connected keyboard/mouse

It wont however automatically start the display on the external monitor, i need to open the laptop and login and then it will.

Any solution?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of closing the lid of the laptop you can use the **cycle display modes** shortcut <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd>. On both of the laptops I use there is such a function key also. If I do it like this after the resume of suspend it enables the same monitor as before the suspend. Also, if you want to skip logging in on wakeup, you can set this using System settings > Security & Privacy > Locking

Comment: This is not an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The idea would be to tell lightdm to use the same settings that you use for the monitors.

So, login into elementary with the external monitor connected, set up your displays the way you want in System Settings -> Displays (mark the external display as primary by clicking its star in the upper left corner). Save you configuration.

Now, copy the `~/.config/monitors.xml` file to `/var/lib/lightdm/.config/` (you'll need sudo for this).

Reboot and hope for the best.

Another way is detailed here [Multi-monitor config for greeter](https://www.reddit.com/r/SolusProject/comments/8coffz/multimonitor_config_for_greeter/)

EDIT: if using cp to copy the file, you'll have to use the `--remove-destination` flag to avoid the `cp: not writing through dangling symlink` warning:
`sudo cp --remove-destination ~/.config/monitors.xml /var/lib/lightdm/.config/`

Comment: The first instruction gave worked when rebooting, but did not solved the problem of wakup from the suspended state to external monitor.

Comment: Does it work if you power-cycle the external display before waking up the laptop from sleep?

Comment: @duality, hello! Please don't flag answers for technical issue, instead make a comment for clarification if need. Have a nice day!

Comment: Sorry, I’m relatively new to stack exchange. I will comment on future from now on, thank you